# How to call next() in the beforeRouterEnter guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, router

I have been stuck on this issue for hours now.
I am using Vue3

I am trying to use a `beforeRouterEnter` guard to check what user role is currently signed in, and based on that re-direct the user to appropiate route.

After submitting the login form (From login page) the `userRoleId` is stored in the vuex, and i get re-directed to a homepage. The homepage has the following script:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      if (vm.$store.getters.userRoleId == USER) {
        next("/us");
        return;
      }
      if (vm.$store.getters.userRoleId == ADMIN) {
        next("/ad");
        return;
      }
      if (vm.$store.getters.userRoleId == SUPER_ADMIN) {;
        next("/sa");
        return;
      }
        next();
    });
  },
```

I keep getting following warning 'The "next" callback was called more than once in one navigation guard when going from "/" to "/". It should be called exactly one time in each navigation guard. This will fail in production.'

The error is there when: I am NOT LOGGED in and get moved to the else block (As soon as the  `next()` line is reached), or when i am logged in and from inside whiever `if` statement is true as soon as `next()` is reached - causing the re-direct to not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mistake to call `next` inside `next` callback. The navigation has already been finished at that moment, this should have been a redirect with `router.push` instead, and this kind of logic belongs to component `mounted` (`next` callback runs after it) rather than router guard.

There should be no redirects here because they are unnecessary. A store is *global* and can be imported directly rather then accessed on `vm`.

It should be:

```
import store from '...';
...
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  if (store.getters.userRoleId == USER) {
    next("/us");
  } else if ... {
    ...
  } else {
    next();
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This makes a lot of sense. However the script shown here is inside a component that does have access to `store` but only via the following syntax `this.$store` - Keyword here being the `this` which is not accessible inside of `beforeRouteEnter`

Comment: Yes, you don't have an access to route component instance inside router guard because it doesn't exist yet, also the first navigation happens before the app is mounted, so there may be no instances at all. So import a store, that's what the answer says. That's the point of having *global* store. It can be accessed globally in the app, not only inside a specific component.

Comment: thank you. I will import the store as suggested m